# Удаление символа $ внутри переменной

Tags: php, json

Есть часть кода:

```
foreach( $priceoverview_list as $key=>$element ) {
 $jsondataitems = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents ($element) );
 array_push($total, preg_replace("/$/i", "", $jsondataitems['median_price']));
}
```

`$jsondataitems['median_price']` содержит цену в `$`, нужно убрать сам символ, для того чтобы рассчитать все цены.

Использую функцию `preg_replace`, но символ `$` не убирается. Как можно убрать?

Comment: *Использую функцию preg_replace, но символ $ не убирается* — приведите, пожалуйста, пример того, как пытаетесь убрать симвло `$`.

Answer (score 2):

видимо саму замену Вы написали так

```
preg_replace('/$/', '', $string);
```

А в этом случае символ доллара совпадает с концом строки Замена его на пустую строку ничего не даст. Его нужно заэкранировать.

```
$string = preg_replace('/\$/', '', $string);
```

интересное замечание. Вот так

```
$string = preg_replace("/\$/", '', $string);
```

работать не будет. Так как в двойных скобках php пытается интерполировать переменные, а комбинация '\$' - это начало особой комбинации - `\${1}` (число может быть разным). За деталями - в документацию.

Решить можно просто

```
$string = preg_replace("/\\$/", '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Не выходит

```
foreach( $priceoverview_list as $key=>$element ) {
$jsondataitems = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents ($element) );
$string = $jsondataitems['median_price'];
$string = preg_replace("/\\$/", '', $string);
array_push($total, $string);}
```

Результат

```
Array ( [0] => $0.03 [1] => $0.23 [2] => $1.30 [3] => $21.96 [4] => $1.58 [5] => $2.98 [6] => $18.01 [7] => )
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вообще использовать регулярки для такой простой операции?
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php

```php
str_replace('$', '', $jsondataitems['median_price'])
```

Обратите внимание на одинарные кавычки, а не двойные - тогда $ не будет восприниматься как начало имени переменной.

Comment: Не выходит все равно, например если поставить символ '0' на замену, то будет менять, но '$' не меняет

Comment: есть подозрение, что там разные символы доллара.

Comment: Не знал что символы доллара разные бывают, но в целом да - можно попробовать просто скопировать тот символ что приходит, а не набирать вручную. Еще можно просто игнорировать первый символ, вообще не разбираясь что это такое substr($jsondataitems['median_price'], 1). Ну предварительно можно обрезать пробелы и проверить что это не цифра.